# Which is the private key?

Tags: ssl, openssl

I bought a ssl certificate for my site, but I do not know which one is the private key.
Here are the available files:

- CACertificate-INTERMEDIATE-1.cer
- CACertificate-ROOT-2.cer
- PKCS7.p7b
- ServerCertificate.cer

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meta: this is not a programming or development Q and will likely be voted offtopic.

**None of them.**

The (normal) sequence is:

1. you generate a key pair, or a private key which implies the matching public key, on your machine
2. you create a CSR (Certificate Signing Request) containing your public key, which is signed using your private key. With some software steps 1 and 2 are combined.
3. you send or submit the CSR to a CA, and also provide proof of identity and if applicable payment; the details of this step can vary depending on the CA you use, the type of cert you request (especially the validation), and who or what you are
4. the CA validates your identity (and payment) and 'issues' a certificate for you
5. the CA gives you your cert, plus the related CA certs needed to form a trust chain; this is often one intermediate plus a root (as in your Q) but other combinations are possible.

You are looking only at step 5. **You need to look back at step 1** (and possibly 2).

Comment: 'With some software steps 1 and 2 are combined' but it is important to note that there are still two separate outputs, and that the private key never gets anywhere near tha CA.